f2py - understanding how to pass an integer (and avoiding message Deprecated NumPy 1.25.)
I am using f2py to link my old Fortran codes to Python. Although I did not have much trouble doing it, I still don't know how to handle integers. For instance, below is a piece of Fortran code where some integers are used with intent(inout) (mlag, nyt, nut, and net).
subroutine maxlags(iext, nump, degree, nsuby, mlag, npt, nnt, nyt, nut, net)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: nump, degree, nsuby
integer, intent(in) :: iext(nump, degree, nsuby)
integer, intent(inout) :: mlag, npt(nsuby), nnt(nsuby), nyt, nut, net
...
end subroutine maxlags

In python, if I define them as
nst = np.array([0])
nyt = np.array([0])
nut = np.array([0])
net = np.array([0])

calling the subroutine works, the values of mlag, nyt, nut and net are updated, but a warning msg comes out

/var/folders/sj/q_5xy_n50ps10lg75p99wbw80000gn/T/ipykernel_87520/378702212.py:18: DeprecationWarning: Conversion of an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated, and will error in future. Ensure you extract a single element from your array before performing this operation. (Deprecated NumPy 1.25.)

If I define them as
nst = np.int32(0)
nyt = np.int32(0)
nut = np.int32(0)
net = np.int32(0)

there is no warning msg anymore, however the values of mlag, nyt, nut and net are no longer updated.
How do I get rid of the warning msg?  Or is there another to define integers to avoid the warning msg and get their values updated?
Many thanks.
PS. Output of print(.maxlagm.doc)
maxlagm(iext,nst,npt,nnt,nyt,nut,net,[nump,degree,nsuby])
Wrapper for maxlagm.
Parameters
iext : input rank-3 array('i') with bounds (nump,degree,nsuby)
nst : in/output rank-0 array(int,'i')
npt : in/output rank-1 array('i') with bounds (nsuby)
nnt : in/output rank-1 array('i') with bounds (nsuby)
nyt : in/output rank-0 array(int,'i')
nut : in/output rank-0 array(int,'i')
net : in/output rank-0 array(int,'i')
Other Parameters
nump : input int, optional
Default: shape(iext, 0)
degree : input int, optional
Default: shape(iext, 1)
nsuby : input int, optional
Default: shape(iext, 2)

See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/python-usage.html#scalar-arguments

I don't know mauch of Python, but this has probably to do with the way Python is passing the arguments and that differs between scalars and arrays.

Try making them 0d arrays like:
nst = np.array(0)

Notice that the square brackets have been removed.
Alternatives include squeezeing or reshapeing the 1d arrays after creating them, but this is more direct.

Most likely, you should use np.array(0, dtype='i') to exclude spurious transformations. Of course, you need to look at the output of print(maxlags.__doc__), unfortunately, @user3749165 did not attach it.

Many thanks.  No warning msg!  I should have thought of that but I didn't.   Would you mind also posting the alternatives?

If you already had an array with only one element (e.g. nst = np.array([0])), you can remove the length-one dimensions like nst.squeeze(). You can also reshape it to 0d like nst.reshape(()). (Effectively the same here, but phrased according to how we normally think of these more general functions.)
